# Visualising the real time trajectory path using markers

Tags: ros, rviz, markers, markers.rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to publish a list of markers, based on the data from the msg subscribed. I'm not able to visualise it, though I change the marker Ids!

Thanks in advance!

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0 
        rospy.Subscriber("/arm_1/arm_controller/cartesian_velocity_command",TwistStamped, self.event_in_cb)
        rospy.sleep(0.5)

    def event_in_cb(self,msg):
        self.waypoints = msg
        self.a = list()
        self.a.append(self.waypoints.twist.linear.x)
        self.a.append(self.waypoints.twist.linear.y)
        self.a.append(self.waypoints.twist.linear.z)
        self.show_text_in_rviz()

    def show_text_in_rviz(self):
        self.marker = Marker()
        self.marker_publisher = rospy.Publisher('visualization_marker', Marker, queue_size=5)
        self.marker = Marker(
                    type=Marker.SPHERE,
                    id=0,
                    lifetime=rospy.Duration(1000),
                    pose=Pose(Point(self.a[0]/10**5,self.a[1]/10**5,self.a[2]/10**5), Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1)),
                    scale=Vector3(0.05, 0.05, 0.05),
                    header=Header(frame_id='arm_link_5'),
                    color=ColorRGBA(0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.8))
        self.count+=1
        self.marker.id = self.count
        self.marker_publisher.publish(self.marker)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("trajectory_interactive_markers_node", anonymous=True)
    trajectory_interactive_markers = TrajectoryInteractiveMarkers()
    rospy.sleep(0.5)
    rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279558/visualising-the-real-time-trajectory-path-using-markers/) by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2018-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @pmuthu2s,

I've tested your code and it worked after I select the right `frame_id`.

In my case I had to change the `frame_id` to `hokuyo_laser_link` but just because my robot doesn't have a link named `arm_link_5`.

You have to check if your robot have a link named `arm_link_5`. You can see the "tf tree" with `rosrun tf view_frames`. That command will generate a `frames.pdf` file that you can use to see the link names of your robot.

Once you open RViz with `rosrun rviz rviz`, you also have to select the right "Fixed Frame". In my case the frame was `world`. You could select "any" link found on `frames.pdf`.

Since I didn't have a topic named `/arm_1/arm_controller/cartesian_velocity_command` that publishes message of type `TwistStamped`, I just created a topic named `/tutorial` that publishes `std_msgs/String` and subscribed to that topic (just for simplicity) on the `TrajectoryInteractiveMarkers` class.

I've created that topic with: `rostopic pub /tutorial std_msgs/String "data: 'Hi'" -r 2`

I've also created a [video](https://youtu.be/0BlFQ8F5vhc) that shows the steps mentioned here.

Since the marker is only published when a message from `/arm_1/arm_controller/cartesian_velocity_command` is received, you have to make sure that topic is publishing.

You can do that with any of the commands below:

`rostopic echo /arm_1/arm_controller/cartesian_velocity_command`

`rostopic hz /arm_1/arm_controller/cartesian_velocity_command`

The modified code I've used is shown below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker
from geometry_msgs.msg import TwistStamped, Pose, Point, Vector3, Quaternion
from std_msgs.msg import Header, ColorRGBA, String


class TrajectoryInteractiveMarkers:
    
    def __init__(self):
    self.count = 0 
    # rospy.Subscriber("/arm_1/arm_controller/cartesian_velocity_command",TwistStamped, self.event_in_cb)
    self.marker_publisher = rospy.Publisher('visualization_marker', Marker, queue_size=5)
    rospy.Subscriber("/tutorial", String, self.event_in_cb)
    rospy.sleep(0.5)

    def event_in_cb(self,msg):
    self.waypoints = msg
    self.a = [1, 1, 1]
    #self.a = list()
    #self.a.append(self.waypoints.twist.linear.x)
    #self.a.append(self.waypoints.twist.linear.y)
    #self.a.append(self.waypoints.twist.linear.z)
    
    self.show_text_in_rviz()

    def show_text_in_rviz(self):
    self.marker = Marker()
    
    self.marker = Marker(
                type=Marker.SPHERE,
                id=0,
                lifetime=rospy.Duration(1000),
                pose=Pose(Point(self.a[0]/10**5,self.a[1]/10**5,self.a[2]/10**5), Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1)),
                scale=Vector3(0.05, 0.05, 0.05),
                header=Header(frame_id='hokuyo_laser_link'),
                color=ColorRGBA(0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.8))
    self.count+=1
    self.marker.id = self.count
    self.marker_publisher.publish(self.marker)
    rospy.loginfo('msg published')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("trajectory_interactive_markers_node", anonymous=True)
    trajectory_interactive_markers = TrajectoryInteractiveMarkers()
    rospy.sleep(0.5)
    rospy.spin()
```

If you still have any question, just take a look at the [video](https://youtu.be/0BlFQ8F5vhc).

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2018-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2018-01-13**:
Hey thanks alot!Video was nice ! Also, I wanted to update that, I had a problem because of thes lines pose=Pose(Point(self.a[0]/10**5,self.a[1]/10**5,self.a[2]/10**5), Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1)),
scale=Vector3(0.05, 0.05, 0.05)
But after I changed the scale and threshold, it worked fine

**Comment by [gubertoli](https://answers.ros.org/users/34045/gubertoli/) on 2018-03-12**:
Great.
What is the best approach to keep a constant refresh instead of forcing the "tutorial" topic to callback ? (for high frequency marker - fast dynamics)